# INSERT INTO with default values for a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, sql-insert

I have a problem to insert the data into 1 table with 1 column

Name: user_id

Column: id

I am trying to add 1 line in this column with this query:

```
INSERT INTO user_id (id) VALUES ()
```

The problem is the above is invalid, I want the id take the last value id +1

This is not a syntax problem because this query works:

```
INSERT INTO user_id (id) VALUES (4)
```

So, I do not really know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to insert an empty row?

Comment: use id column as identity insert

Comment: When INSERT, you have to pass the same number of values as the number of columns specified.

Comment: I need it to refer to other tables

Comment: Perhaps `INSERT INTO user_id (id) VALUES (default)`?

Comment: you can use sequence and use it in default value and you can also refer it to other table

Comment: Wokrs thaks you  !

Comment: So where the right answer? please put answer not in comment so we know and learn too..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `id` column is defined as `serial` or `identity` you can specify a column list and set the column value to `default`:

```
insert into user_id (id) values (default);
```

This also works if you have more columns, e.g:

```
insert into users (id, firstname, lastname) 
values (default, 'Arthur', 'Dent');
```

Or you can leave out the column list completely and request the default value(s) for all columns:

```
insert into user_id default values;
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL supports the `default values` statement.

So this will work:

```
create table t (id serial primary key);

insert into t 
    default values;
```

The syntax is described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html).